# Quand utiliser « à tout à l'heure », « à plus tard », « à la prochaine », « à bientôt » ?

Tags: usage, sens, salutations

On peut traduire « à plus tard », « à la prochaine », « à bientôt » littéralement, en anglais, par « *see you later* », « *see you next time* », « *see you soon* ».  Cependant, on peut dire « *see you soon* » à quelqu'un même si on n'a pas l'intention de le voir dans peu de temps.

Dans quelles situations utilise-t-on ces expressions ?  Quels sont leurs synonymes et leurs alternatives ?

Comment: Pour moi, c'est tout synonyme et j'utilise indifféremment. S'il y a une différence, je la verrais plutôt dans le niveau de langue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

La plupart du temps :

- *À tout à l'heure* désigne un moment particulier (dans les heures qui suivent) que les interlocuteurs savent tous identifier. Il n'est pas forcément très précis. Par exemple, ça peut être « le moment où je reviendrai, après avoir fait ce que j'ai à faire ». La variante *à tout de suite* indique un retour ou (au téléphone) une arrivée imminente.
- *À plus tard* s'emploie lorsqu'il est sûr, ou très vraisemblable, que les personnes vont se revoir dans la même journée (ou soirée), mais le moment et les conditions ne sont pas nécessairement convenus.
- *À la prochaine* s'emploie en général entre amis, ou lorsqu'on est sûr qu'il y aura une « prochaine » sans que l'on ait à s'en inquiéter (rendez-vous ou rencontres régulières). Lorsque les conditions d'une nouvelle rencontre sont plus incertaines, on peut opter pour la variante *à une prochaine*.
- *À bientôt* insiste sur le fait qu'on espère revoir bientôt ses interlocuteurs (ce peut être un vrai sentiment ou une marque polie d'attention). En particulier c'est approprié lorsqu'il n'est pas du tout évident qu'une nouvelle rencontre ait lieu, dans ce cas il peut être suivi de « j'espère ».