# "à tout de suite" et "à tout à l'heure"

Tags: expressions

On utilise "à tout de suite" pour une arrivée imminente, et sinon "à tout à l'heure". Mais quelle est la limite pour une arrivée 'imminente' ? Si j'arrive dans 5 minutes, je dirais évidemment "à tout de suite", mais si c'est 15 minutes, ou 30 ?
Ou est-ce bêtement 1 heure la valeur limite pour dire "à tout à l'**heure**" ? Parce que ça me semble long pour dire à tout de suite si j'arrive dans trois quarts d'heure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

« À tout de suite » ne devrait pas être utilisé pour des périodes qui excèdent une demi-heure ou trois quarts d'heure.

Ce n'est pas tout bêtement une limite de une heure qui est spécifiée, et possiblement ne l'a jamais été ; il serait intéressant de savoir cela. Deux ou trois heures peuvent constituer la période de temps que l'on peut impliquer en utilisant cette expression mais pas tellement plus ; en passant du matin à l'après-midi on dira « à cet après-midi ». Par exemple quelqu'un qui va prendre son repas juste avant midi et qui revient après une pause traditionnelle de deux heures pour son repas peut dire « à tout à l'heure »; il en va de même pour des évènements similaires.

L'[étymologie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tout_%C3%A0_l%E2%80%99heure#fr) pour cette expression semble manquer, tout au moins en grande partie puisque elle provient de la combinaison de la préposition « à » avec l'expression « tout à l'heure », laquelle est plutôt ennuyeuse puisqu'elle peut être utilisée aussi bien pour parler d'un moment dans le futur proche que dans le passé récent. « À tout à l'heure » ne sert que pour le futur proche.

D'après le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/heure) on ne peut pas dire qu'à l'origine l'expression de base (tout à l'heure) aurait été  fondée sur la notion d'une heure de temps précise ;

> h) 1549 tout a ceste heure « tout de suite, à l'instant même » (Est.); 1628 tout à l'heure « id. » (Sorel, Francion, I ds Dub.-Lag.); 1647 tout à l'heure « il y a un instant » (Corneille, Héraclius, II, IV, éd. Ch. Marty-Laveaux, V, 181); 1694 (Ac. : On dit... tout à cette heure, tout à l'heure pour dire, Dans un moment);

Anecdote intéressante

Il y a maintenant de nombreuses années, lorsque le *BBC World Service* pouvait encore être écouté au moyen d'une radio ondes courtes, il y avait une émission hebdomadaire sur cette station dans laquelle l'animateur, quand il prenait congé de ses auditeurs jusqu'à la semaine suivante, les quittait régulièrement avec un « à tout à l'heure ».

Comment: Merci pour la réponse approfondie. Avec le premier commentaire de jlliagre, on dirait qu'il y a une zone floue entre 10 et 45 minutes où les deux seraient acceptables.

Comment: @Herby C'est exactement cela ; une personne pourra dire « à tout à l'heure » et une autre « à tout de suite » dans un certain intervalle qui n'est pas trop court ni trop long,  comme ça se comprend facilement, parce que ces termes sont approximatifs ; je crois que s'ils correspondaient à des nombres précis on utiliserait plutôt les nombres, ce que l'on fait d'ailleurs parfois avec des expressions complémentaires : « à tout de suite, dans une dizaine de minutes ou un peu plus »,…

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a pas de limite précise mais je ne dis plus *à tout de suite* si l'intervalle attendu dépasse quelques minutes.

Ce sera donc *à tout à l'heure* dès une dizaine de minutes.

Voir aussi: [Quand utiliser « à tout à l'heure », « à plus tard », « à la prochaine », « à bientôt » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4490/quand-utiliser-%C3%A0-tout-%C3%A0-lheure-%C3%A0-plus-tard-%C3%A0-la-prochaine-%C3%A0-bi)

Comment: Ce serait évidemment une question d'opinion personnelle, et donc pour vous c'est une dizaine de minutes. Peut-être que le contexte changerait la donne ? Si on se trouve à 20 minutes en voiture et qu'on démarre immédiatement, ne pourrait-on pas dire "à tout de suite" ?

Comment: Bien qu'il n'y ait pas de seuil précis, je serais assez surpris d'entendre quelqu'un me dire *à tout de suite* pour vingt minutes.